# COUNTA and INDIRECT together

Tags: excel, vba

Any help would be appreciated.  I have seen the indirect formula used a lot but I'm not sure if I can string together all that I am trying to do here.

1. I have created within the `X column` of `SS Sales` a formula that calculates the data range based on install dates.  So 1/1/13 to 4/1/13 may equal `(DT14:BL41)`. The `X column` gives me this answer depending on dates that change.
2. I need to use the range determined by `cell X2` in `SS Sales(DT14:BL41)` in a COUNTA formula to count what is actually open on the calendar, which is on a separate sheet within the same workbook.
3. This is what I am trying but it doesn't work:

`=COUNTA('install calendar copy'!(INDIRECT('SS Sales'!X2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `'SS Sales'!X2` to contain the text string `'install calendar copy'!DT14:BL41` then `=COUNTA(INDIRECT('SS Sales'!X2))` should give you what you want.

Comment: Excellent :) thanks I just needed to add 'install calendar copy' abd one more ) at the end and it worked so = COUNTA(INDIRECT(X2)))  THANK YOU SO MUCH